# How to make file_exists to Work(Php)?

Tags: php

I have made this code, to save images to a remote directory, but i have not an Idea where to code do nothing if file exists:

```
  $album_name = $row['album'];
if(file_exists("cdcovers/$album_name.jpg")){
    <---here
 } 

else {
//save images
$imageString =       file_get_contents(LastFMArtwork::getArtwork($row['artist'], $row['album'],    true, "large"));
$save = file_put_contents('/home/link/public_html   /cdcovers             /'.$row['album'].'.jpg',$imageString);
}
```

Can i have some ideas?

Comment: Well, what do **you** want to do if the file exists?

Comment: file_exists works all by itself. there is nothing you have to do to make it work.

Comment: Why do you have all those spaces in the pathname when you call `file_put_contents`?

Comment: Instead of calling `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`, you can juse use `copy()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!file_exists("cdcovers/$album_name.jpg")){
    //save images
    $imageString = get_contents(LastFMArtwork::getArtwork($row['artist'], $row['album'],    true, "large"));
    $save = file_put_contents('/home/link/public_html   /cdcovers             /'.$row['album'].'.jpg',$imageString);
}
```

If the file does NOT exist, save it. It will do nothing if it does.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the few times I would use a negative if statment

```
 $album_name = $row['album'];
if(!file_exists("cdcovers/$album_name.jpg")){
  //save images
  $imageString = file_get_contents(LastFMArtwork::getArtwork($row['artist'], $row['album'],    true, "large"));
  $save = file_put_contents('/home/link/public_html   /cdcovers /'.$row['album'].'.jpg',$imageString);
}
```

I feel it makes the code cleaner, and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

remove the "<---here" and you are done...

```
if(blah==TRUE){ 
/*do nothing */
} ELSE {
/*do something*/  
code to do something goes here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You an either leave the "if" block blank and write your working code in the "else" block or you can go with @keith and @thomasw_lrd answers.

Or you can give a "file already exist" message in the "if" block.